# Unable to cast Session variable Containing a List Of object to list

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, session-variables

Why Is the following code producing error of **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object** Even when i am using the set session method inboth of the button click events?

```
public partial class MergePopUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{

List<MergeAccounts> Mlist = new List<MergeAccounts>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private void SetSession()
{
    if (Session["Account"] == null)
    {
        Session["Account"] = Mlist;
    }
}


protected void AddToMergeList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MergeAccounts obj = new MergeAccounts();
    obj.AccountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(AccountNumber.Text);
    obj.PinNumber = Convert.ToInt32(PinNumber.Text);
    int temp = obj.IsAccNoValid(obj.AccountNumber, obj.PinNumber);
    if (temp == 0)
    {
        FoundOrNot.Visible = true;
        FoundOrNot.Text = "Enter a valid Pin Number against this Account number";
    }
    else
    {
        DataSet MyDataSet = obj.ShowDetails(obj.AccountNumber, obj.PinNumber);
        foreach (DataRow myRow in MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            AccountTitle.Text = myRow["Title"].ToString();
            Balance.Text = myRow["Balance"].ToString();
            CreationDate.Text = myRow["CreationDate"].ToString();
        }
        obj.AccountTitle = AccountTitle.Text;
        obj.Balance = Convert.ToDouble(Balance.Text);
        obj.CreationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(CreationDate.Text);
        Mlist.Add(obj);
        Session["Account"] = Mlist;
        SetSession();
    }
}
protected void AddNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox i in this.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList())
    {
        i.Text = null;
    }
    FoundOrNot.Visible = false;
}
protected void CheckList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetSession();
    Response.Redirect("Merge.spx");
}

}
```

Comment: can you show us where you initially fill your Session["account"] ? because right now you are trying to pass whatever is in Session["account"] to your Mlit. Which is probably not working because you are not filling the session right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are the two buttons on the same page? If so, create a method accessible to both buttons where the session variable is set. Make sure you check if it's already set so that it's only set once.

```
private void SetSession()
{
   if(Session["Account"] == null)
      Session["Account"] = "Value";
   else
      //what do you want to do here
}


protected void button1_click(.....)
{
    SetSession();
    //do something
}

protected void button2_click(....)
{
    SetSession();
    //redirect
}
```

by this your session is always set whether first button or second button is clicked

Comment: Yup two buttons are onsame page ..
 ... is the value a c# Keyword that u used here??

Comment: that should be replaced with the value you want to assign to the session variable

Comment: Shall i show u the code where i am using this stuff? ... i can edit my question to show u the code

Comment: Yes. the code for the buttons, and the page_load of the second page. Just like @Jane Doe said

Comment: You still need to step through your code and locate where the problem is. Has the object reference problem gone away. One more thing - Your MList variable at the top of the page - whenever the second button is pressed, that statement would be executed again - resetting MList to empty list.

Comment: if you click the 'CheckList_Click' button before you click 'AddToMergeList_Click' you are always going to get the null reference because the session will equal null, and so the session will be filled with Mlist, which at that point will still be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Session["Account"] is probably null.

Comment: Tunmise fasipe: Actuslly i am taking List in session variable in one Button Click event and redirecting the page from 2nd button click event .. thats the reson this is Null ... Is there some way out that i can preserve my session variable this way??

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point here

```
Mlit = (List<MergeAccounts>)Session["Account"];
```

Then press F5 to step through your application and put your mouse on Session["Account"] to inspect the value - it is probably null

Comment: Tunmise fasipe: 
Actuslly i am taking List in session variable in one Button Click event and redirecting the page from 2nd button click event .. thats the reson this is Null ... **Is there some way out that i can preserve my session variable this way??**